# How to mute screen reader reading out "role"

Tags: javascript, typescript, accessibility, ibm-wcm

```
<mwc-button
      role="radio"
      aria-checked="${option.id === this.answer}"
      >
      option
</mwc-button>
```

screen reader always reads out xxx,radio. Is there a way to stop it from reading out radio in the end?

Comment: Kind of the point? It tells visually impaired users that it is a radio button

Comment: Yeah, this is expected behaviour, what are you trying to achieve / why do you not want it to read it out?

Comment: I actually made it looks like a button: yes, no, decline to answer. But would like it to say"listed three options: yes, unselected; no, unselected; decline to answer, selected". reading out the "radio" is not desired.